# Adding string arrays to a 2d String array through iteration

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

Am trying to create an array which holds the String arrays created from a utilising the `String.split()` method on a string which is input through a loop.

```
int N = in.nextInt();
String [][] defibDetails = new String[N][];
in.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    String DEFIB = in.nextLine();
    String [] details = DEFIB.split(";");
    defibDetails[i][]=details;
}
System.out.println(defibDetails[0][0]);
```

I would like the System.out to be the substring of `DEFIB` before the first `;` where loop counter `i = 0`.  Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Do you know the size of your total input? String arrays need to be given a predetermined size. Have you thought of using lists. List<List<String>> details = new ArrayList<>(); Is the 'in' object in your code the Scanner class?

Comment: Read the error message you get from the compiler, fix the error (it should be `defibDetails[i] = details;`, and you will have the expected behavior. You can't expect a program to do something if it doesn't even compile.

Comment: Unfortunately the length varies. Am open to using any form of collection but quite new to Java and don't know the best for a given application.  Looked at lists but couldn't work out the 2d syntax for getting the value back.  Would it be `list.get(0).list.get(0)` ?

Comment: nizet the code is actually for a 2d array so I don't think I want to do that unless you can expand on why?

Comment: No. list.get(0) returns a List<String>. Sna dyou can call get(0) on a List<String> to get its first element. So it's list.get(0).get(0). But you can use two instructions to make it clearer: List<String> firstList = list.get(0); String firstString = firstList.get(0);

Comment: why? To make the code compile. There is no such thing as a 2D array. What you have (i.e. `defibDetails`) is in fact an array of arrays. So, to assign a value to the ith index of this array, you use `defibDetails[i] = details;`

Comment: OK, I have heard an array of arrays referred to as a 2d array and assumed that as with 2d point reference you always needed  two array coordinates.  Understand now though so thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here: `defibDetails[i][]` ; it should be like this: `defibDetails[i]`
You've got a two dimensional array, so fist dimension is particular array of "array of arrays". Second is particular element of this array.
So `defibDetails[i]` means array #i, `defibDetails[i][j]` means element j in array i.

```
int N = in.nextInt();
String [][] defibDetails = new String[N][];
in.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    String DEFIB = in.nextLine();
    String [] details = DEFIB.split(";");
    defibDetails[i]=details; // <<<<<<<<
}
System.out.println(defibDetails[0][0]);
```

http://ideone.com/Dr9Aci

Comment: Thank you. Thought since it was 2d needed to use constant 2d notation.  Has fixed the issue.